# Weird encoding issue, reading from webpage

Tags: java, html, encoding, character-encoding

I'm reading a website into a string. Although I'm using `UTF-8`, German special characters are not getting displayed correctly. This is especially weird as one ö is displayed correct, while others have a weird special character in front of them:

[image]

The website has defined `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and gets displayed in a web browser without issues.

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get correct german texts using your method. I added buffer.toString() at the end of your code and tried to get the source for the website (http://www.bundesregierung.de/Webs/Breg/DE/Startseite/startseite_node.html).
Could the problem be your system setup? Maybe German texts are not installed in your OS or browser has some encoding issues if you are seeing the values in the browser?
Also, I am not sure your intent of making method like this but if you are parsing some website, I prefer using Jsoup libraries (http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: @HarryCho I've tried using Jsoup.connect and get(). The result is the same.

Comment: I have a feeling that its your system language issue. I am getting the texts correctly and from my IDE, the character ö's value is 246 in decimal which is correct from (http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp). Can you provide the actual URL you are testing?

Comment: I managed to avoid the issue now by using regex: `.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9öäüß\\\\s]", "")`. Not perfect, but working...

Comment: Hmm.. I'm glad that you found a workaround. However I'm still getting the correct results using your code and the URL. I tested the results I got from the code against the source and they are exact match.

Comment: @HarryCho I forgot to mention it  earlier, but I'm using Android, could that be an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure but Android may be the issue if you are using old versions. After googling a bit, recent android versions like 4.X supports multiple languages.